# Spring, Spring Security and Thymeleaf, Is user Logged In Or Not

Tags: spring, maven, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am implementing a Spring MVC Web Application. I have added Spring Security to my application. I wanted to add a navigation bar, where Login and Logout buttons appear and disappear accordingly to whether the user is logged in or not. I searched the web and I saw thatthis can be done by using Thymeleaf. Therefore, I added it to my project and tried to experiment around it.
Even though I tried the following, nothing work.

```
<div th:if="${name!='eleni'}">
   <div>Welcome, ${name}</div>
</div>

<div th:if="${name=='eleni'}">
   <div>Welcome, ${name}</div>
</div>
```

Both of the "Welcome, ..." would appear. The parameter ${name} works correctly, if I'm logged in as 'eleni' it displays it, if not it's left blank.
  Afterwards, I tried using sec:authorize:

```
<div sec:authorize="!hasRole('USER')" > Not a User </div>
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('USER')" >  User </div>
```

Again both of these would show up.

I'm posting some of the relevant code.
In my navigation.jspf I've included:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
 xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
```

In my SecurityConfiguration.java:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("eleni").password("1")
            .roles("USER");
}
```

And finally my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.todo</groupId>
<artifactId>todo-springmvc</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
         <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4 -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
         <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
         <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                    <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

I genuinely do not know what I am doing wrong, I feel pretty dumb at this point. I feel like a logical explanation would be some sort of incompatibility of thymeleaf with the rest of the dependencies. I am sorry for the wall of text, yet I need a solution or some advice!
   Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: Looks like Thymeleaf doesn't process your files at all. Could you add your show configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for **(Spring security 4 With Thymeleaf )** :

```
            <div class="navbar-form navbar-right"> 

              <div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"> 
                <a class="btn btn-success"th:href="@{/logout}">Logout</a> 
              </div> 

              <div sec:authorize="isAnonymous()"> 
                <a class="btn btn-success" th:href="@{/login}">Login</a>
              </div>

            </div>
```

**More Details:**

```
            <div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
              This content is only shown to ALL USER.
            </div>

            <div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
              This content is only shown to ADMIN.
            </div>

            <div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
              This content is only shown to USER.
            </div>
```

Try this for **: ( Spring Security 5 With Thymeleaf )**

```
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-info navbar-dark fixed-top">
                  <a class="navbar-brand" th:href="@{/auth/login}" sec:authorize="!isFullyAuthenticated()">Login</a>
                  <a class="navbar-brand" th:href="@{/logout}" sec:authorize="isFullyAuthenticated()">Logout</a>
            </nav>
```

Comment: Tried ( Spring Security 5 With Thymeleaf ), does not work for me.